# Excel Nested IF's for Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Thanks in advance, I am doing something dumb that I'm just not seeing.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(L36),  IF( L36 < K3, "PASS", "FAIL"), "PASS", "N/A")
```

why doesn't his work?

Comment: waiting for my face meeting palm moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first `IF` statement has four arguments (one too many!). You probably just want to remove the last "PASS" argument?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(L36),IF(L36<K3,"PASS","FAIL"),"N/A")
```